# How to perform onClickListner in fragment Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have facing some issues regarding to the button click

here is code,

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);

        ImageView Send_Button = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.HelpBtnBlack);
        Send_Button.Click += delegate 
        {

        };
    }
    public override void OnClick(View V)
    {
        //do sth...

    }
```

the error is on FindViewById

Comment: coul you give to us the error message please

Comment: The name 'FindViewById' does not exits in the current context

Comment: Use FragmentManager.FindViewById();

Comment: are you try ``return inflater`` in the end of ``OnCreateView`` after declare ``send_button``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);

            ImageView Send_Button = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.HelpBtnBlack);
            Send_Button.Click += delegate 
            {

            };
            return view;
        }
        public override void OnClick(View V)
        {
            //do sth...

        }
```

Comment: Hey Karstriot hi, again I want one answer from you that if I want to call a layout on click on that button then how to write a code for that??? please suggest

Comment: same as ImageView you give layout id and refference that id and just layout.Click += delegate {};

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the `View`:

```
var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
```

Then you can call `view.FindViewById<your_control_type>(Resource.Id.your_control_id)`

update your code to this for button:

```
var Send_Button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.HelpBtnBlack);
```

or this for ImageView:

```
var Send_Button = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.HelpBtnBlack);
```

Comment: Thanks Milen, but I have face same issue on FindViewById I this the possition I put is wrong?